# Using Eval with Sum() and Count() with ASP.Net EntityFramework and ListView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding

I am working on my first project with the Entity Framework and am having some difficulty displaying advanced information with the EntityDataSource and a ListView.

For example, given the two entities:

**Item**
Name
Price

**Order**
Number
Items   <---- Navigation Property to Items contained in the Order

I want to display a list of all orders with a column with the total number of items in the order and a column with the sum of the prices of all items in the order.

I am using an EntityDataSource configured as follows:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="eds" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=NDSEntities"
DefaultContainerName="NDSEntities" EnableFlattening="False" Include="Items"
EntitySetName="Orders"></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

In the ItemTemplate of the ListView, I can write the order number as follows:

```
<%# Eval("Number") %>
```

I had trouble figuring out how to display a count of items in the order. I tried using Items.Count() function in select statement in the EntityDataSource but that didn't work. Eventually I figured out I could do the following in my ItemTemplate:

```
<%# Eval("Items").Count() %>
```

Now I am stuck trying to get the sum of the items. I am stuck here. I have tried using

```
<%# Eval("Items").Sum(Function(i) i.Price)%>
```

but I get the following error:

> Public member 'Sum' on type 'EntityCollection(Of Item)' not found.

This confuses me because I know that Sum is a method of EntityCollection(Of ).

My two questions are as follows:

Am I getting the item count correctly?

How should I go about getting the sum of the prices of the items?

Answer (score 2):

> I know that Sum is a method of EntityCollection(Of )

[No it isn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352821.aspx).

It's an extension method defined on `Enumerable`. You might not have included `System.Linq`.

Comment: Ah. That explains it. I have instead created a function in my code behind and am passing the EntityCollection as a parameter. From there I can perform a Sum and get to total price.

Answer (score 2):

use this
'<%# Eval("Items.Count") %>'

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is like this:

```
<%# ((ICollection<Item>)Eval("Items")).Sum(i => i.Price) %>
```